# How do I print out select items from my dictionary?

Tags: python

Extremely basic I know but here's my code:

```
dict = {'blue':475, 'Green':530, 'Red':650, 'IR':800, 'UV':300}
x = dict['IR'] + dict['UV']
x //= 2
dict['Visible'] = x
print('IR',dict['IR'], 'UV',dict['UV'], 'Visible',dict['Visible'])
```

I want to just print the last 3 (not red, but visible) items from my dictionary. Although it works I'm thinking there has to be a more straight forward method.

Thanks

Comment: `dict` does not have order. So there is no first or last in a dictionary.

Comment: it is unclear what you want because you say you want "to print the last 3" but you don't want to print red which is in the last 3.

Comment: Not too much improvement apart from skipping the creation of some variables which can added directly to print.

Comment: it is unclear what you want

Comment: I would like to see: IR : 800, UV : 300, and Visible : 550

Comment: I'm aware thats what my code does, but I was curious if theres a less clunky way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary ordering in Python is messy, and the details of the implementation have changed many times throughout the Python releases.

As of Python 3.7, [the `dict` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) guarantee that iteration order of the `dict` matches insertion order. This was also true in 3.6 for CPython implementations. Relevant quote:

> *Changed in version 3.7*: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

In Python 3.5 and earlier, the ordering was not guaranteed at all (and was sometimes intentionally non-deterministic to prevent people from relying on it!).

So, if you want to print the 3 most recently-inserted elements in Python 3.7 (or in CPython's 3.6 implementation), you can do this:

```
my_dict = { . . . }
# Append some more stuff to my_dict

dict_in_insertion_order = list(my_dict.items())
# a list of key-value tuples, like [('IR', 800), ('UV', 300), ('Visible', 550)]
last_3 = dict_in_insertion_order[-3:]
```

This uses Python's list slicing, where the starting index of -3 indicates "3 from the end."

**Edited to add**:

Of course, if you don't care about the *general*-case solution, you could always just specify the keys you want to print, like so:

```
for key in ['IR', 'UV', 'Visible']:
    print(key + ':', my_dict[key])  # Prints: IR: 800, then UV: 300, etc.
```